# The C code `printf("%ls", L"αβγ");` prints nothing at all, why is that?

Tags: c

I know `L` prefix indicates a string literal.

This code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%ls", L"abc");
    return 0;
}
```

prints the string literal "abc" verbatim while the following code

```
printf("%ls", L"αβγ");
```

gives nothing, although simple string

```
printf("αβγ");
```

can be displayed well, why is that?

Comment: `L"..."` denotes a `wchar_t[]`, not specifically a string literal... `"..."` is also a string literal, though typed `char[]`